# Expect: How to log to to an open file?

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to log the input/output of expect to an open file. The man page says that this can be done with the `-open` flag to `exp_log_file`. I leep getting usage errors:

```
84 > expect
expect1.1> set f [open xxx.txt w]
file7
expect1.2> exp_log_file -open $f
usage: log_file [-info] [-noappend] [[-a] file] [-[leave]open [open ...]]
    while executing
"exp_log_file -open $f"
expect1.3>
```

What am I doing wrong?

If it makes a difference, I am using expect version 5.44.1.11 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Comment: did you try it without opening the file first? `exp_log_file -a www.txt` or what have you?

Comment: @Ryan `exp_log_file -a www.txt` works just fine.

Comment: I tried your scenario and it works fine on Mac OSX Lion 10.7, Tcl 8.5.9. Have you tried the `-leaveopen` flag?

Comment: @HaiVu Thanks for letting me know. Some of my "customers" are on Lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a lot of messing around, it would seem that there is a bug in the expect version 5.44.1.11. Unfortunately this is the version installed out of the box on Mac OSX 10.8.0 (Snow Leopard).

I have compiled version 5.45 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/files/
This version works as expected (pun intended).

Comment: lol nice! well gj on fixing it, i hate them pesky bugs, prolly more frustrating than just lacking knowledge

Comment: Thanks for describing that this was a bug and that updating to latest fixed it.